# Implementing new procedures / guidelines in companies

Tags: io-psychology

I'm teaching evidence-based practice and implementation science to midwifery students, i.e. how to evaluate research findings e.g. regarding new therapies and diagnostics and how to plan the implementation of new procedures into clinical practice. The question of how new procedures/guidelines can be implemented most successfully into an organization is obviously pretty complex and depends e.g. on the willingness of the co-workers to change their behaviour, but also on the organizational culture, leaders etc. Several models exist how implementations should be planned or evaluated ([Williams et al., 2015](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.nedt.2014.11.012)), but I feel like the field is not very advanced in terms of theory building and the possibility to predict the success of implementation.

I assume there exist a lot of similarities to 'implementation science' or whatever it is called in organizational psychology, i.e. I assume that there exists also research on how to implement new procedures/guidelines in private companies etc. What is a good starting point/literature review for this kind of research?

Williams, B., Perillo, S., & Brown, T. (2015). [What are the factors of organisational culture in health care settings that act as barriers to the implementation of evidence-based practice? A scoping review.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.nedt.2014.11.012) *Nurse education today, 35*(2), e34-e41.

Comment: Great question! Welcome to the community!